# Warning message saying the installation may fail in such circumstances

Tags: installation, boot-failure, memory-usage

The warning message says
"256MB of memory are required only 222 are available.
The installation may fail in such circumstances. Do you wish to continue anyway?"
Im confused here i have 37GB of free space i even deleted some programs in my computer just to install this! i already tried accepting it but then, after rebooting and trying to use linux it stuck up in the middle of startup! and remain there.. i cant even shut my computer down even pressing the power button didnt work after waiting for 16 hours! what shall i do?  I uninstalled the OS and then tried to re install it but the warning message still appears.. even after deleting some of my files its still constant at 222MB available is it a bug? should i ignore it?

Comment: you should clarify which version of ubuntu you are installing e.g. 12.04?  Is this ubuntu/xubuntu/lubuntu ?

Comment: @fossfreedom none of them will install without a warning with under 256Mb memory available.

Comment: @Rinzwind - I thought that requirement applied to the GUI live CD's - the alternate text CD should be less?

Comment: Damn. "If your system has less than 192 MiB of system memory, use the Alternate Installation CD. " I missed that line :D

Answer (score 1):

[Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) != [disc space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive).

Your system seems to only have 256 MiB Memory. You need to check if you can add memory modules onto your motherboard since 256 MiB  is the minimum required memory (for any flavor of Ubuntu except CLI server: server = 128 MiB,  desktop = 1GiB, netbook = 386 MiB, Xubuntu and Lubuntu = 512 MiB).